# Information about gtalkservice

Tags: android, push-notification, google-talk, internet-connection

I'm trying to find more information about keeping a open internet connections for push trough messages or data. I've read that the xmpp protocol could be suitable for this, and that it's replaced by the gtalkservice of android.

Unfortunately i have no be able to find more package information about com.google.android.gtalkservice on the internet.

Does anyone know where i can find this information?

Thanks.

Comment: This post is excellent and will help you understand the gtalk service http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2010/06/28/a-peek-inside-the-gtalkservice-connection/ In fact, a few searches find the apk file for gtalkservice. http://ishare.iask.sina.com.cn/f/14270095.html?from=like